# How to aggregate an accumulative list in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe like this one below.

```
    +--------+-------------------+
    | worker |  day  |    tasks  |
    +--------+-------------------+
    |   A    |   2   | 'read'    |
    |   A    |   9   | 'write'   |
    |   B    |   1   | 'read'    |
    |   B    |   2   | 'write'   |
    |   B    |   4   | 'execute' |
    +--------+-------------------+
```

I need to group dataframe by **[col_1, day]** and gain an acummulated list of tasks.
e.g. if ***worker 'A'*** has the task 'read' in day 2, then the tasks for day 9 should be
**['read', 'write']** list.

---

The desired dataframe looks like this:

```
    +--------+-------------------------------------+
    | worker |  day  |          aggregation        |
    +--------+-------------------------------------+
    |   A    |   2   | ['read']                    |
    |   A    |   9   | ['read', 'write']           |
    |   B    |   1   | ['read']                    |
    |   B    |   2   | ['read', 'write']           |
    |   B    |   4   | ['read', 'write', 'execute']|
    +--------+-------------------------------------+
```

---

I tried to use cumsum

```
df = df.groupby(['worker', 'day'])['tasks'].apply(list).reset_index(name='aggregation').cumsum()
```

But it aggregates an accumulation for all the columns and not inside the groups for certain column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward method (although not ideal in terms of performance — then again you're storing lists in columns so your mileage will vary) is to do a `groupby` and `cumsum` with lists.

```
df['tasks'].map(lambda x: [x]).groupby(df['worker']).apply(pd.Series.cumsum) 

0                    [read]
1             [read, write]
2                    [read]
3             [read, write]
4    [read, write, execute]
Name: tasks, dtype: object
```

Or, very similarly,

```
(df.assign(tasks=df['tasks'].map(lambda x: [x]))
   .groupby('worker')['tasks']
   .apply(pd.Series.cumsum))

0                    [read]
1             [read, write]
2                    [read]
3             [read, write]
4    [read, write, execute]
Name: tasks, dtype: object
```

Since you're cumsumming objects (and not numeric data), we need to apply `pd.Series.cumsum` instead of calling the cythonized `GroupBy.cumsum` which chokes on python lists.

Comment: `df['tasks'].map(lambda x: [x]).cumsum()` works on `list` while `df['tasks'].map(lambda x: [x]).groupby(df['worker']).cumsum()` don't,  What's the reason behind this? Any internal implementation limitation?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma not sure but it looks like `GroupBy.cumsum` is cythonized and expects numeric data by default. I imagine it's some kind of bug, but not a big one.

Comment: @cs95, thank you very much for the detailed answer. It really helped.